# How to access react-router v3 prop in function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using [refresh-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/refresh-fetch) for authentication token refreshing. If the app receives not 200 http status code response I need to handle that by redirecting the user to logout page. How could I achieve this using react-router v3.

```
browserHistory.push('/logout');
```

I think this is not an option because I'm using basename.

```
const refreshToken = () => {
  return fetchJSONWithToken(`${API_ROOT}user/login/refresh`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ refresh_token: retrieveToken() })
  })
    .then(({body}) => {
      saveToken(body.access_token, body.refresh_token);
      return body;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //TODO: redirect user to /logout
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Or maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why isn't `browserHistory.push('/logout');` not an option, did you try it our

Comment: That's my thinking tell me if I'm wrong. In production react is installed in a subfolder, so I need to use basename. If I use `browserHistory.push('/logout');` the basename is gone because I'm creating new browser history and not accessing old one which contains basename. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example with locations ? But if you have a basename, it must me stored somewhere, so recreate your url with it and redirect to something like : `basename+'/logout'` no?

Comment: That's not an option, I need to access router history instance, not create new one. @ChrisR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your browserHistory instance and reuse it.

Example:

```
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'

// Run our app under the /base URL.
const yourCustomHistoryWithBasename = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: '/base'
})
// Re-use the same history, which includes the basename
yourCustomHistoryWithBasename.push('/logout') // push /base/logout
yourCustomHistoryWithBasename.replace('/logout') // replace current history entry with /base/logout
```

[Source for this example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v2/docs/BasenameSupport.md)